# Trying to update Enthought Canopy 64 bit v1.2.0.1610 to 1.3.0.1705 on a Mac

Tags: updates, enthought, package-managers, canopy

The Canopy Package manager tells me there is an update available from Canopy v1.2.0.1610 to 1.3.0.1715 (64 bit running on a Mac with Mavericks).  When I chose  "install and relaunch" canopy closes but does not install the update or relaunch.  When I relaunch manually I'm still at version 1.2.0.    I also tried "install on quit," which didn't work either.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Canopy and sorry for the trouble. Please report the issue through canopy so that we can have access to the log files and try to identify the origin of the issue. If trying again doesn't help, I would recommend you download Canopy again since our website will give you 1.3 installers.

HTH,